# Android - How to dynamically change fragment layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-screen

I have a tablet app with an about fragment which displays my company's datas. I would like to change my layout dynamically with screen orientation while im on the page but i didn't found how yet.

If someone got the solution, thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@Yume177, i found how to do it :

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.about);
    rl.removeAllViews();
    rl.addView(View.inflate(myView.getContext(), R.layout.about, null));
}
```

I have 2 RelativeLayout both named "about.xml", with one layout in a dir **res/layout-sw720dp/about.xml** with my drawable for portrait mode and **res/layout-sw720dp-land/about.xml** with my landscape drawable. When i rotate my tablet, my layout fits perfectly. Hope i'll help you

Comment: when i do this it gives nullpointerexception? are not there any setcontentciew?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this out http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/steven-byle/android-tutorial-optimizing-phones-and-tablets-fragments

If you are using ABS + viewpager it'll be kind of difficult (if you find a solution i'm interrested ! see my last question)

Here is the official doc
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Links die, post the actual answers.