# Can Fargments change their layout based on orientation?

Tags: android, android-fragments

My UI design for my app is to have a single activity host multiple fragments which will be swapped based on what option the user clicks from the sliding menu. I am trying to keep just one `Activity` in the app. (*Please tell me if this is a good design decision*). I have the swapping-the-fragments part figured out.

However, I do not know how a fragment's layout can be changed based on the orientation. For example, my app has this fragment which shows a list of items in portrait mode. In landscape, I want it to switch to a grid view.

Activities can change layouts based on orientation, I am aware of that. What about fragments ?

Comment: You can SIMPLY  use two /res/layout folders and have two different layouts inside (but then in Java code you need to get the ids fro the proper objects). Just make a /res/layout-port/activity.xml and a /res/layout-land/activity.xml. the two activity.xml files can differ totally, if you so want.

Comment: @ArtooDetoo Two `Activity` then. Not one :)

Comment: No... just one. You see, in code you point your ONE Activity to the same layout resource file (but Android chooses if it's the port or the land flavour to be used). Just refer to the different control names in code. Say, you have a TextView in Portrait and an ImageView in Landscape, you would create two different objects depending on orientation change (which, as you know, calls the onCreate method again). It's different if we are talking of the "1 to 2" fragments. Then, yes, a second activity is required, as per the official [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig)
```

> Called by the system when the device configuration changes while your
>   component is running. Note that, unlike activities, other components
>   are never restarted when a configuration changes: they must always
>   deal with the results of the change, such as by re-retrieving
>   resources.
>
> At the time that this function has been called, your Resources object
>   will have been updated to return resource values matching the new
>   configuration.

Overriding the above method of the `Fragment` may help in changing the view dynamically. For example, as below:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.about);
    rl.removeAllViews();
    rl.addView(View.inflate(myView.getContext(), R.layout.about, null));
}
```

Taken from: [Android - How to dynamically change fragment layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829154/android-how-to-dynamically-change-fragment-layout)

Comment: `Fragment` does not have a method called `findViewById()`. Do you override `Fragment`'s `onConfigurationChanged()` method in this example?

Answer (score 2):

When we work with Activities in Android, defining different layouts for different screen orientations is easy. The only thing we need to do, is to create two *.xml files with the same name for layouts in two separate directories (res/layout/ and res/layout-land/). In Fragments it’s not that easy. In such case, we need to perform additional operations in order to achieve our goal.
Fragment in Android is not re-inflated on configuration change, but we can recreate layout and repopulate view manually.
We need to create two layouts for different orientations of the screen in the same way as for Activity:

res/layout/my_fragment.xml
res/layout-land/my_fragment.xml
Then, we need to put code shown below to our fragment.
Of course, it requires little adjustments depending on concrete project.