# Set a different layout in Fragment's onResume() method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a situation where I need to set different layouts for the fragment upon returning from an Activity that does some modifications to that database.

How do I set a different layout for the fragment in the onResume() method of that fragment?

I basically need to copy exactly the same code to the onResume method, but the problem is with this part of the code, I can't understand how I can implement it in the on onResume() method :

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list, container, false);
```

Here is the code for the OnCreateView method:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        dataSource = new ExpensesDataSource(context);
        dataSource.open();

        //if Expenses dataSource is not empty create the list of expenses and set a listview
        if (dataSource.getAllExpenses().size() != 0) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list, container, false);

            //prepare the list of Expenses to be put into an adapter
            preparedListData = prepareListData();

            //load the sorted list of lists of expense into the adapter
            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(context, preparedListData);

            expListView = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
            expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            expListView.setOnChildClickListener(this);
        }
        //else show a layout saying the list is empty
        else {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_empty, container, false);
        }

        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried a solution from this page? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829154/android-how-to-dynamically-change-fragment-layout

Comment: I think you should consider instead merging your two layouts into one layout that can be adapted for both cases, perhaps by conditionally hiding some views.

Comment: Well the problem is that the fragment performs as expected when I change the orientation. The activity gets rebuilt and I get elements taken off or added to the listview. But, I want the elements to be taken off/added without having to rotate the screen, just by returning from the activity - in the onResume() method of the fragment that is.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem. It's a bit nasty, but this is all I can do. Assuming you have the currently chosen fragment saved in your activity, this is what you need to do in your activitys onResume:

```
if(currentFragment instanceof YourDynamiclyChangingFrament) {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            YourDynamiclyChangingFrament yourDynamiclyChangingFrament= new YourDynamiclyChangingFrament();

            transaction.replace(R.id.container, yourDynamiclyChangingFrament, YourDynamiclyChangingFrament.class.getSimpleName());
            transaction.commit();
        }
```