# Button's onClick method modifying a global variable in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

The code in my fragment is structured as follows:

```
public class FragmentScanQR extends Fragment {
    ...
    private Button qrFromCameraBtn;
    private View rootView;
    ...

public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.qrsource, container, false);
        qrFromCameraBtn = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.qrViaCameraBtn);

        qrFromCameraBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab1, container, false);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
```

The `onCreateView` method of fragment returns a value of type android.view.View. The `qrFromCameraBtn` button's `onClick` method modifies the same View variable. In the output, when I click on the botton, the layout doesn't change to `R.layout.fragmenttab1` (which I wish to achieve) but remains the same. How can I do this?

Comment: just out of curiosity..why do want to do that? you can achive this by replacing the fragment

Comment: If my answer below helped, please accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you need, you want to replace your first fragment with a new one. You can do that like so:

```
//Where Article fragment is your new fragment.
ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just replace the layout,this link might help you.
[Android - How to dynamically change fragment layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829154/android-how-to-dynamically-change-fragment-layout).
Just add the following code on button click method

```
 qrFromCameraBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.about);
rl.removeAllViews();
rl.addView(View.inflate(myView.getContext(), R.layout.about, null));
        }
    });
```